# Texture mapping on voxel model in Open GL

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, wavefront, texturing

I'm following a video series about Open GL on YouTube using LWJGL, so far I've managed to render 3d models and texture them properly using the obj format. I want to use voxel-based models for my game so I went in the software MagicaVoxel, exported a textured example with the obj format, but the texture is not mapped correctly. Indeed, some colors seem to be correctly mapped, but other faces have the entire texture on them.

Here is a picture of the expected result:

[image: Expected result]

and the actual result:

[image: Actual result]

I think the problem comes with the texture and the way opengl interpolate it, the texture is a 1*256 line with colors, and on the obj file only the desired colors are put on the uv coordinates.

I made a simpler example to help understand what is going on: just 3 cubes aligned with each other, and a 3-pixel long texture with 3 different colors, here is the code of the obj file and the texture is too small to be seen but it's really just 3 colored pixels.

```
# normals
vn -1 0 0
vn 1 0 0
vn 0 0 1
vn 0 0 -1
vn 0 -1 0
vn 0 1 0

# texcoords
vt 0.25 0.5
vt 0.5 0.5
vt 0.75 0.5

# verts
v -0.1 0 0
v -0.1 0 -0.1
v -0.1 0.1 0
v -0.1 0.1 -0.1
v 0.2 0 0
v 0.2 0 -0.1
v 0.2 0.1 0
v 0.2 0.1 -0.1
v -0.1 0 0
v -0.1 0.1 0
v 0 0 0
v 0 0.1 0
v 0.1 0 0
v 0.1 0.1 0
v 0.2 0 0
v 0.2 0.1 0
v -0.1 0 -0.1
v -0.1 0.1 -0.1
v 0 0 -0.1
v 0 0.1 -0.1
v 0.1 0 -0.1
v 0.1 0.1 -0.1
v 0.2 0 -0.1
v 0.2 0.1 -0.1
v -0.1 0 0
v 0 0 0
v 0.1 0 0
v 0.2 0 0
v -0.1 0 -0.1
v 0 0 -0.1
v 0.1 0 -0.1
v 0.2 0 -0.1
v -0.1 0.1 0
v 0 0.1 0
v 0.1 0.1 0
v 0.2 0.1 0
v -0.1 0.1 -0.1
v 0 0.1 -0.1
v 0.1 0.1 -0.1
v 0.2 0.1 -0.1

# faces
f 3/2/1 2/2/1 1/2/1
f 4/2/1 2/2/1 3/2/1
f 5/1/2 6/1/2 7/1/2
f 7/1/2 6/1/2 8/1/2
f 11/2/3 10/2/3 9/2/3
f 12/2/3 10/2/3 11/2/3
f 13/3/3 12/3/3 11/3/3
f 14/3/3 12/3/3 13/3/3
f 15/1/3 14/1/3 13/1/3
f 16/1/3 14/1/3 15/1/3
f 17/2/4 18/2/4 19/2/4
f 19/2/4 18/2/4 20/2/4
f 19/3/4 20/3/4 21/3/4
f 21/3/4 20/3/4 22/3/4
f 21/1/4 22/1/4 23/1/4
f 23/1/4 22/1/4 24/1/4
f 29/2/5 26/2/5 25/2/5
f 30/3/5 27/3/5 26/3/5
f 30/2/5 26/2/5 29/2/5
f 31/1/5 28/1/5 27/1/5
f 31/3/5 27/3/5 30/3/5
f 32/1/5 28/1/5 31/1/5
f 33/2/6 34/2/6 37/2/6
f 34/3/6 35/3/6 38/3/6
f 37/2/6 34/2/6 38/2/6
f 35/1/6 36/1/6 39/1/6
f 38/3/6 35/3/6 39/3/6
f 39/1/6 36/1/6 40/1/6
```

As you can see for each face, the 3 UV coordinates picked up for the 3 vertices **are the same**, but in OpenGL, this is the result (they are supposed to be red, blue and yellow):

[image: 3 Cubes result]

Here is my OBJ file reader code (in Java), that I call to create the vao and stuff to render:

```
public static RawModel loadObjModel(String fileName, Loader loader) {
        FileReader fr = null;
        try {
            fr = new FileReader(new File("res/" + fileName + ".obj"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't load file!");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line;
        List<Vector3f> vertices = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        List<Vector2f> textures = new ArrayList<Vector2f>();
        List<Vector3f> normals = new ArrayList<Vector3f>();
        List<Integer> indices = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        float[] verticesArray = null;
        float[] normalsArray = null;
        float[] textureArray = null;
        int[] indicesArray = null;
        try {

            while (true) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                if (line.startsWith("v ")) {
                    Vector3f vertex = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]), Float.parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
                    vertices.add(vertex);
                } else if (line.startsWith("vt ")) {
                    Vector2f texture = new Vector2f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]));
                    textures.add(texture);
                } else if (line.startsWith("vn ")) {
                    Vector3f normal = new Vector3f(Float.parseFloat(currentLine[1]),
                            Float.parseFloat(currentLine[2]), Float.parseFloat(currentLine[3]));
                    normals.add(normal);
                } else if (line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    textureArray = new float[vertices.size() * 2];
                    normalsArray = new float[vertices.size() * 3];
                    break;
                }
            }

            while (line != null) {
                if (!line.startsWith("f ")) {
                    line = reader.readLine();
                    continue;
                }
                String[] currentLine = line.split(" ");
                String[] vertex1 = currentLine[1].split("/");
                String[] vertex2 = currentLine[2].split("/");
                String[] vertex3 = currentLine[3].split("/");
                
                processVertex(vertex1,indices,textures,normals,textureArray,normalsArray);
                processVertex(vertex2,indices,textures,normals,textureArray,normalsArray);
                processVertex(vertex3,indices,textures,normals,textureArray,normalsArray);
                line = reader.readLine();
            }
            reader.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        verticesArray = new float[vertices.size()*3];
        indicesArray = new int[indices.size()];
        
        int vertexPointer = 0;
        for(Vector3f vertex:vertices){
            verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.x;
            verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.y;
            verticesArray[vertexPointer++] = vertex.z;
        }
        
        for(int i=0;i<indices.size();i++){
            indicesArray[i] = indices.get(i);
        }
        return loader.loadToVAO(verticesArray, indicesArray, textureArray);

    }

    private static void processVertex(String[] vertexData, List<Integer> indices,
            List<Vector2f> textures, List<Vector3f> normals, float[] textureArray,
            float[] normalsArray) {
        int currentVertexPointer = Integer.parseInt(vertexData[0]) - 1;
        indices.add(currentVertexPointer);
        Vector2f currentTex = textures.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[1])-1);
        textureArray[currentVertexPointer*2] = currentTex.x;
        textureArray[currentVertexPointer*2+1] = 1 - currentTex.y;
        Vector3f currentNorm = normals.get(Integer.parseInt(vertexData[2])-1);
        normalsArray[currentVertexPointer*3] = currentNorm.x;
        normalsArray[currentVertexPointer*3+1] = currentNorm.y;
        normalsArray[currentVertexPointer*3+2] = currentNorm.z; 
    }
```

Here is my fragment shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec2 pass_textureCoords;

out vec4 out_colour;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main(void){

    out_colour = texture(textureSampler,pass_textureCoords);
}
```

Here is my vertex shader:

```
#version 400 core

in vec3 position;
in vec2 textureCoords;

out vec2 pass_textureCoords;

uniform mat4 transformationMatrix;
uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;
uniform mat4 viewMatrix;

void main(void){

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * viewMatrix * transformationMatrix * vec4(position.xyz,1.0);
    pass_textureCoords = textureCoords;
}
```

And here is my render method called every frame:

```
public void render(Entity entity,StaticShader shader) {

        TexturedModel texturedModel = entity.getTexturedModel();
        RawModel model = texturedModel.getRawModel();
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(model.getVaoID());
        
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);
        
        Matrix4f transformationMatrix = Maths.createTransformationMatrix(entity.getPosition(), entity.getRotation(), entity.getScale());
        shader.loadTransformationMatrix(transformationMatrix);
        
        GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);



        GL11.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texturedModel.getTexture().getID());
        
        GL11.glDrawElements(GL11.GL_TRIANGLES, model.getVertexCount(),GL11.GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);
        
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
        GL20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);

        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
```

I don't understand what I'm missing, and again it already worked for a blender model with a large texture:

[image: working model]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Wavefront OBJ file loader really only works in a very particular case, namely, when no texture coordinates or normals are shared by any two vertices, so that v, vn and vt specifications have a 1:1 correspondence to each another.
This generally is not the case, though. Leaving out the fact that your Wavefront OBJ file loader also only works when all 'f' lines come after all v, vt and vn lines (which is also not always the case), then you still have a few other problems.
So the main problem as is currently is that you assume a 1:1 correspondence between 'v' and 'vt' lines, which is not the case. Generally, you cannot simply use the 'v' index (as specified via the first '/'-delimited value in an 'f' line) as your OpenGL element buffer index, because OpenGL only has one single element index, to index into position, texture and normals arrays uniformly, whereas the Wavefront OBJ file format has three different indices, each for position, textures and normals separately.
So, what you *should* do is rethink/rewrite your Wavefront OBJ file loader so that it basically collects all position (v), texture coordinates (vt) and normals (vn) information and then whenever you encounter a face (f) you append the position, texture and normals information at the specified indices (in the 'f' line) into your final result buffers. You cannot simply use a single index derived from the position index of the 'f' line.
You either don't use any indices at all or simply use a contiguous incrementing index as your OpenGL element buffer.

But first, I highly recommend reading an actual specification for the Wavefront OBJ file format, such as this: http://paulbourke.net/dataformats/obj/

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try to modify my obj loader because I'm using LWJGL 2 unfortunately.

Comment: I got it to work, the thing I was missing was that every vertex HAS to be unique, it can't have 2 different uv coordinates for instance. So I left behind the index buffer (I just count from 0 to n), and "duplicated" all the vertices for each face, which is a bit more memory and calculation time consuming but simpler for the moment.